# Delete row in google spreadsheet from a specific range based on values from a specific cell range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a little help with my script.

> First, here is a link to the ss:
>   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TgG64irjoxkV9wKlT5bEnaNEWlGyOlNxVoLxOmQZ2BA/edit?usp=sharing

I want to delete rows from sheet "Team 1" (range: A15:A41), based on values from sheet "Overview" (range: C4:C12).

Basically, if any value from C4:C12 is found in A15:A41, the row where is found should be deleted.

> Ex. for my ss: C4 = 3, that means in sheet "Team 1", row 17 should be
>   deleted.

My script so far:

```
function deleteRows() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('Overview');

  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Team 1');

  var r1 = s1.getRange("C4");

  var v1 = r1.getValue();

  var r2 = s2.getRange("A2:A28");

  var v2 = r2.getValues();

 for(var i=28;i>0;i--)

    if(v1[i]=v2)

      s2.deleteRow(i+1);
};
```

But the only thing I get is to delete all the rows, the criteria is not taken into consideration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to delete the rows of the sheet `Team 1` by comparing the cell "C4" in the shee `Overview` with the cells "A2:A28" in the sheet `Team 1`.

For this, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `v1` is a value which is not an array. `v2` is 2 dimensional array.

  - In this case, at `v1[i]=v2`, the 2 dimensional array is tried to put to `undefined`. By this, `v1[i]=v2` is always existing. So `s2.deleteRow(i + 1);` is always run. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- When you want to compare the values, please use `==` and/or `===` instead of only `=` in the if statement.
- The 1st index of the array is `0`.
- When `s2.getRange("A2:A28")` is used, the offset is required to be added to the delete row number.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
for (var i = 28; i > 0; i--)
  if (v1[i] = v2)
    s2.deleteRow(i + 1);
```

To:

```
for (var i = v2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  if (v2[i][0] == v1)
    s2.deleteRow(i + 2);
```

- `v2.length` is used for retrieving the length of array.

#### References:

- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: Wow, it actually worked. Thanks. If I may add: What if I want to compare the whole range C4:C10, instead of just cell C4, how can I modify the script? And if is a match to delete that row. Or is it necessary to copy the whole script for each cell in particular?

Comment: @Bogdan Moineagu Thank you for your response.